# Why is the port listed only in the specific format of netstat?

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, port, netstat

I have Tomcat and I am trying to bind to 2 specific ports (using custom connectors). E.g. port `A` and port `B`.
Problem:
When I do `netstat -a |grep A` I do **NOT** see the port listed.
If I do `netstat -antp` I see both ports `A` and `B` listed.

What is the difference between the commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-n` option is the difference.  Without it, `netstat` converts well-known ports such as 3306 and 80 into names such as mysql and http.

If `A` is a well-known port and `B` isn't, only one of your ports will be listed by the first command.

If a port is well-known, it should be listed in `/etc/services`.

Comment: +1 Ah!Port `A` is `8443`.How can I verify if it is transformed to a name?

Comment: grep 8443 /etc/services – should be mapped to pcsync-https

Answer (score 6):

By specifying `-n` you tell netstat to use the port number instead of the service name. If you look at the output of `netstat -a` you will see that the port numbers are instead human-readable service names. These are mapped from `/etc/services`, so if you are listening on port 80 you will see `*:http` or `hostname:http`, and if you are listening on port 8080 you will see `*:webcache` or `hostname:webcache`.

From the netstat man page on Fedora 16:

```
  --numeric , -n
       Show  numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host,
       port or user names.
```

Comment: But why is my port listed only in the second form?

Comment: That's what `netstat` does. By default, it tries to show human-readable ports (unless you specify `-n`). When it succeeds, the port number does not appear in the output.